# Problem using table parameter in subcircuit

Tags: ltspice, simulation, spice, error, subcircuit

I am trying to use a subcircuit to replace a normal resistor for an FMEA.
The .sub file looks like this:

```
.subckt testResistor In Out
.step param testResistorIterrator 0 4 1
.param BaseResistance= table(testResistorIterrator,   0, 1T,    1,  1,  2, 1.5k,    3, 0.5k,    4,1k)
.param BlockResistance = table(testResistorIterrator, 0, 1T,    1, 1T,  2, 1T,      3, 1T,      4,1)
R§Base Out In {BaseResistance}
R§Block Out 0 {BlockResistance}
.ends testResistor
```

In theory it should step iterate through 0 to 4 and assign the two resistors a value based on the step, however when I try to integrate the subcircuit in this test circuit:
[image]

It gives me these errors:

```
WARNING: Can't resolve .param baseresistance=table(testresistoriterrator, 0, 1t, 1, 1, 2, 1.5k, 3, 0.5k, 4,1k)
WARNING: Can't resolve .param blockresistance=table(testresistoriterrator, 0, 1t, 1, 1t, 2, 1t, 3, 1t, 4,1)
Questionable use of curly braces in "râ§base out in {baseresistance}"
    Error: yet unevaluated parameter in: "[baseresistance]"
Questionable use of curly braces in "râ§block out 0 {blockresistance}"
    Error: yet unevaluated parameter in: "[blockresistance]"
Fatal Error:  Unable to find definition of model "baseresistance"
```

Did I declare something wrong, or is my entire setup wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run a `.step` command within a subcircuit.  The way to solve this is to make `testResistorIterrator` a regular parameter and then pass the stepped value from your top-level schematic to your subcircuit.  You also need to define a default value to `testResistorIterrator` within your subcircuit.  In other words, something like this:

```
.subckt testResistor In Out
.param testResistorIterrator=0
.param BaseResistance = table(testResistorIterrator,   0, 1T,    1,  1,  2, 1.5k,    3, 0.5k,    4,1k)
.param BlockResistance = table(testResistorIterrator, 0, 1T,    1, 1T,  2, 1T,      3, 1T,      4,1)
R§Base Out In {BaseResistance}
R§Block Out 0 {BlockResistance}
.ends testResistor
```

Then you right-click your subcircuit symbol and define either of the `Value2`, `SpiceLine`, or `SpiceLine2` fields (doesn't matter which) as `testResistorIterrator={value}`, as shown below.

[image]